# Adding a Where clause in a blade in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to add the following Where clause in a blade in laravel, but not working :

```
       @if( Auth::user()->grpusers()
       ->where('group_id', $group->id)->first() == True) 
       ->where('join_request', 1)->first() == True) // boolean
```

I'm also not sure if the boolean syntax is correct.
If I remove the boolean line it works fine.

Comment: Why don't you get the value of that boolean in your server and then return a variable storing that value to your view? `return view('my-view')->with('flag', $myBooleanFlag);`.. so then in your view you just: `@if($flag)...@endif`

Comment: Ok, I got this. Thanks HCK

Comment: Wrong syntax, please check your code again.

Comment: I think it is better if you should do that in the controller and just pass the results to your view.

Comment: What you are looking for is probably an `exists` query, which will always return `true` or `false`: `Auth::user()->grpusers()->where('group_id', $group->id)->where('join_request', 1)->exists()`